# USB Audio interfaces not recognized - RODECaster Pro II

Tags: usb, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

**January 2023 Update: I installed a great radio automation app, called Vimar, and it recognized my RCPII USB1 Main that Cinnamon or the rest of the computer GUIs wouldn’t show (See screenshot).[image: Vimar showing both outputs][image: Detailed view of available outputs] It shows on Vimar as « RODECaster Pro II: USB Audio #1 ». I can’t figure why it shows on a specific software, but not on the main Linux Mint sound settings. It’s also worth saying Vimar (radit.org) is also available for Windows, and so I guess I guess it used a cross-platform toolkit to not have to rewrite the whole software for a specific OS. It’s also worth saying that the audio from Vimar isn’t stable, as after the first audio played, both players would redirect audio in either USB 1 Main or USB 1 Chat. It just wouldn’t play on both at the same time, somehow. So maybe Linux Mint doesn’t show USB 1 Main because it can’t handle audio distribution to different outputs? To be continued…**

I'm facing a USB audio problem with my RODECaster Pro II (a USB audio interface/mixer) on my Linux Mint PC.
This mixer as 2 physical USB-C audio ports, both carrying sound in- and out of the computer. But the first USB-C port transports 2 different audio interfaces. So there's USB-Port1-MAIN (duplex) and USB-Port1-CHAT (duplex).

On Windows, both interfaces are detected:
[Windows10 Sound Settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9kvB.png)

Unfortunately, it isn't the case on Linux Mint.
In Linux Mint sound settings:
[Linux Mint Sound utility window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeHIM.png)

In pavucontrol: [PulseAudio Volume Control outputs window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfoiz.png)

Can anyone help? Does anyone have a RODECaster Pro II or something similar to test on?

Thanks.

### EDIT: Rode answered me the device was UAC2-compliant and therefore it should be recognized by the system with the UAC2-compliant Linux builts (I guess they meant kernel?). Could it be that Linux Mint 21 kernel is too old?

INFO: LM**D**E 5 Elsie, kernel 5.10.0-19-amd64

Comment: I was thinking of buying RCP 2, but I hope your issue will be solved first. I read online you might want to test out another USB chipset like an external PCI-e: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08PF8XR73. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335547/how-can-i-make-an-audio-mixer-rodecaster-pro-work-on-ubuntu-20-04-potential-pr